# Another four haikus

Tags: wordplay, poetry

> I can push away,
> Or pull back to me instead,
> Only in certain ways.
>
> I like my brother,
> Though we don't quite look alike,
> He's my one other.
>
> I'm a fickle thing,
> I don't really like to stay,
> But stuck in a ring.
>
> I’m swapped, changed,
> To form two common used tools,
> In groups, I range

Comment: This is four haikus...

Comment: @Joe-You-Know check the edit history; the last haiku was added later :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> An electron?

Haiku 1:

> Being a charged particle, electron could push and pull depending on a charge of another particle.

Haiku 2:

> Electron's one other could be a neutrone, or a positrone

Haiku 2 and 3:

> Stuck in a ring, fickle thing, swapped, changed...  seems to match. Also forms electricity and magnetism - truly commonly used tools

Hope that's right. Would be awesome to guess a riddle correctly XD

Comment: Well done! I thought *no one* was gonna solve it

Comment: Yaay, I'm happy I was the one. Thanks for a cool puzzle. I will look at other ones from you :)

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> The Moon?

I can push away, 
Or pull back to me instead, 
Only in certain ways.

> I think this refers to the tides and how the Moon influences them.

I like my brother, 
Though we don't quite look alike, 
He's my one other.

> The Earth is the Moon’s brother (and his one other), even though they don’t look alike.

I'm a fickle thing, 
I don't really like to stay, 
But stuck in a ring.

> The Moon doesn’t stay in one place in the sky, but it’s stuck in a ring shaped orbit around the earth.

Comment: Interesting, but not right

Comment: @RohitJose Can you specify in what way this doesn't fit? It seems like a pretty solid solution. Or perhaps add or alter a line in your poem that would lead to a more specific answer?

Comment: @Sensoray this should help

Comment: @RohitJose Very nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Take two: Are you a

> Saw

I can push away, 
Or pull back to me instead, 
Only in certain ways.

> A saw is moved back in forth

I like my brother, 
Though we don't quite look alike, 
He's my one other.

> There are many different kinds of saws, (handsaws, circular saws, hacksaw, etc.) that are similar in function but different in appearance

I'm a fickle thing, 
I don't really like to stay, 
But stuck in a ring.

> Again movement to function, a circular saw is one that is stuck in a circular, ring-like motion

I’m swapped, changed,
To form two common used tools,
In groups, I range

> saw blades can be swapped and different blades are used for different things

Comment: Good try, but no